# Matlab standalone executable runs indefinitely in Web-server

Tags: php, matlab, iis, web

when i tried to run a matlab standalone executable using PHP from an IIS server, the program is not stopping and it runs indefinitely. however when i ran the same executable manually,its working fine.

Following is the my matlab code.

```
Pairs=21;

TimeHistories=csvread('Example_Peak_Data.csv'); % reads from a excel file

Sizes=size(TimeHistories);

SampleSize=Sizes(1);

Triggers=Sizes(2)/Pairs;

tot=0;

for n = 1:Triggers

    for nn = 1:Pairs

        tot=tot+1;

        [Peak(tot),Peakind(tot)]=max(TimeHistories(:,tot));


        [Trough(tot),Troughind(tot)]=min(TimeHistories(:,tot));
        Amplitude(tot)=Peak(tot)-Trough(tot);
        AmplitudeMatrix(n,nn)=Peak(tot)-Trough(tot);


    end
end
```

This is just a test program. MCR is installed in the server. Also there is no permission issue in the residing folder. I just couldn't figure out the problem behind this. i am using exec() command in php

Comment: To investigate, try

system("env > /tmp/variables")

from both execution types.
(this comment was initially an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20212367/2987828, Shai migrated it)

Comment: Try to write to a log file for example on every few lines, preferably describing the relevant variables. At least this can help you pinpoint the location of the holdup.